# tensorflow: higher dimensional elementwise subtraction

Tags: tensorflow

I know there is a way to do elementwise arithmetic to a tensor like so.

```
// x is a 4d tensor
y = x - 1
```

But is the same possible if, for example, a 4d tensor (MxNxVxW) is subtracted by a 1 dimensional (M) tensor, such that for every value in the (M) tensor the corresponding (NxVxW) values are subtracted elementwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, for example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a=tf.constant([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[11,12,13],[14,15,16]]])
b=tf.constant([10,20,30])
res=a-b
sess=tf.InteractiveSession()
res.eval()
```

This prints

```
array([[[ -9, -18, -27],
        [ -6, -15, -24]],

      [[  1,  -8, -17],
       [  4,  -5, -14]]])
```

​

Comment: thanks, but do you know why are they being reduced by the last and not the first dimension?

Comment: @user2255757 This is just how tf.subtract defined. If you want to subtract by the second dimension, you could do: b=tf.constant([10,20]) and then res=a-tf.reshape(b,[1,-1,1]). In order to subtract by the first you could do res=a-tf.reshape(b,[-1,1,1]).

Comment: does the same apply for two or more unknown dimensions? For example:
x-y
while x's shape is (?,?,120,120,3) and y's shape is (?,?,1,1,1)